# Issues when printing information from the parent class through child object's __str__ function

Tags: python, oop

```
CHARCLASSDICT = {
    'warrior': {'lvl': 4, 'hp': 50, 'sp': 30, 'mp': 15,
                'str': 10, 'def': 8, 'dex': 8, 'int': 4, 'end': 6, 'fai': 2, 'chr': 4, 'lck': 2},

class LivingBeing(object):
    # Class that defines the values of living beings inside the game space.
    def __init__(self, name, health, strength, defense, dexterity, intelligence, description):
        # Base attributes:
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.description = description

        # Base skills:
        self.strength = strength
        self.defense = defense
        self.dexterity = dexterity
        self.intelligence = intelligence

class Hero(LivingBeing):
    # Base class for the player.
    def __init__(self, playertype):
        # Basic player variables:
        self.stamina = CHARCLASSDICT[playertype]['sp']
        self.mana = CHARCLASSDICT[playertype]['mp']
        self.level = CHARCLASSDICT[playertype]['lvl']
        self.charclass = 'Adventurer'

        # Additional player skill attributes:
        self.endurance = CHARCLASSDICT[playertype]['end']
        self.faith = CHARCLASSDICT[playertype]['fai']
        self.charisma = CHARCLASSDICT[playertype]['chr']
        self.luck = CHARCLASSDICT[playertype]['lck']

        super(Hero, self).__init__('Unknown', 50,
                           CHARCLASSDICT[playertype]['str'],
                           CHARCLASSDICT[playertype]['def'],
                           CHARCLASSDICT[playertype]['dex'],
                           CHARCLASSDICT[playertype]['int'])

player = Hero('warrior')
```

The above code outlines basic variables for my text based RPG.  What I am doing is defining character class information, i.e. values for the class 'warrior' or 'knight', through a dictionary and presenting the user with a raw input to choose their class.  For this example, I simply call 'warrior' when dictating the player class variable: `player = Hero('warrior')`.

That being said, once I apply the values of the dictionary by calling a class instance, I want to be able to confirm the changes with the player.  To do this, I figured creating a `__str__` function in the player class would be the easiest way of doing so.

```
class Hero(LivingBeing):
    def __init__(...)
        ...

    def __str__(self):
        details = """Name: {0}, Class: {1}, Level: {2}, Stamina: {3}, Mana: {4} //
                     STR: {5}, DEF: {6}, DEX: {7}, INT: {8}, FAI: {9}, CHR: {10}, LCK: {11}"""

        return details.format(self.name, self.charclass, self.level, self.stamina, self.mana,
                              self.strength, self.defense, self.dexterity, self.intelligence,
                              self.faith, self.charisma, self.luck)
```

However, the problem I am facing is when I go to `print player`.  It returns an error saying the Hero objects does not have an attribute of strength.  Am I misunderstanding the concept of the `__str__` function and how it works inside of class inheritance?

Comment: Unrelated but using `__str__` to provide debug information is a really bad idea. Use `__repr__` instead and return a string like `<Hero(name=.., class=.., ...)>` - otherwise `print hero` will give you the `__str__` and it'll look like an actual string, not like an object. It easily gets confusing, especially with less verbose `__str__` output on some objects.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the tip! I'm slowly but surely launching myself into the world of OOP in Python.  The information I want to provide is actually the player stats, not really debug info., which I want the player to be able to view in string form.  In this case, when the player is finishing their character, I want to print them their stats w/ the `__str__`, function and confirm if it look correct.  Perhaps I may be misunderstanding what you're saying and replying foolishly, but I though I should clarify that this is information I actively want the player to view.

Comment: I'd use a method `get_stats()` for that. IMO `__str__` (or better `__unicode__`) should be used on objects that are actually string-like.

Comment: I guess that may be a better way of doing it.  I may get better results that way.  Thanks for the quick replies!